# Variable is becoming larger, but the result is for the smallest number?

Tags: objective-c, loops, for-loop

I'm studying Objective-C currently. Today, I ran into a question:

> On a Mac, a short is 2-byte integer, and one bit is used to hold the
>   sign. What is the smallest number that a short can store? What is the
>   largest?

Below is my code, I have a question about the loop. In For Loop, x is becoming larger from 0, like 1,2,3,4,5.....,but the final result is -32768.
I couldn't figure out why the result is a negative number. Same problem with the largest one.

```
short x;
short y;

for (x = 0; x > -1; x++) {
    continue;
}
printf("Smallest short is %d. \n",x);

for (y = 0; y < 1; y--) {
    continue;
}
printf("Largest short is %d. \n",y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, unfortunately is undefined behavior.  The *first* example of undefined behavior in the C spec is

> An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.  C11dr §3.4.3 3

Both `for`  loops incur this undefined behavior.  A *smart* compiler may recognized that and change `for (x = 0; x > -1; x++) { continue; }` into `for (;;) {; }`, an infinite loop or `;` (nothing).

```
for (x = 0; x > -1; x++) {
  continue;
}
for (y = 0; y < 1; y--) {
  continue;
}
```

So anything is possible.  Code could use the following, but that likely is not what this exercise is about.

```
#include <limits.h>
printf("Smallest short is %d. \n", SHRT_MIN);
printf("Largest short is %d. \n", SHRT_MAX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of overflow.

A signed 2-byte integer can be represented by the following 16 bits:

`00000000 00000000`

where the first bit is the sign bit (`0` for positive, `1` for negative). When you increment, you will eventually reach `01111111 11111111` (the largest positive integer) and increment once more to get `1000000 000000` (the largest negative integer). See [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) on why bits are formatted in this way.